# Customize Prompt Color for Pure Theme?

Tags: themes, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I'm currently using the [Pure](https://github.com/sindresorhus/pure) theme for zsh, but the default blue is really dark. Is it possible to change only the blue (i.e. I don't want to install `zsh-syntax-highlighting`)?

Comment: Please consider accepting an answer if it solved your problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the color is set via `%F{blue}` inside the theme the exact color used for `blue` is set in your terminal (most probably).

So to change this color you need to check how to configure those colors for your terminal.

---

*Just as an example here is a super**user** answer for "[How to set color terminal for iTerm2?](https://superuser.com/q/353396/205181)"*

Answer (score 1):

1. change terminal profile
   open terminal

   - cmd + , show terminal profiles
   - change any [ansi colors] that you didnot like

if this is not effect, you need custom your theme

2. custom your theme

   - first find the dir

   `echo $ZSH_CUSTOM`

   - second build the theme file

   `cd ~/.oh-my-zsh/custom
   mkdir themes
   mate themes/xxx.zsh-theme`

   - third fix the ~/.zshrc file change theme:

   `ZSH_THEME="xxx"`

   - fourth open your xxx.zsh-theme, u can change anything.
   - maybe you need copy a sample: https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/tree/master/themes
   - about color u can get information from : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code